# react: how to set focus from a click handler

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

My react-redux based form has a button that should reset the form *and* move focus back to the first input field.
Resetting the content is straight up redux state, but I'm having trouble with the focus.

autoFocus on the first field works only on the initial render.  Is there any sane way to re-trigger it?

If I need to go with explicit element.focus(), where should I call it from? I'm using react-redux, but not redux-forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you keep some info in store to know which element should get focus on page load? Nope? Then why you should do that later?

Trigger `element.focus()` right after dispatching action - you don't need Redux to achieve this, nor Redux to store this state.

Pseudocode could look like this

```
onReset() {
  const action = {
    type: RESET_FORM,
  }
  dispatch(action);

  const element = getElement(); // propably read ref? Find element with [autoFocus] attribute in component?
  element.focus();
}
```

Comment: My original motivation was to limit the view classes to pure, dumb rendering code, free of behavior/state change code, and being able to test all state logic independently of rendering. The difference from default focus handling (which does not pass through my application state) is that it is now explicitly manipulated by my code. But you may be right that a more pragmatic approach is best for this particular problem, and moving all focus control to app-code is not realistic or desirable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
document.getElementById("ElementName").focus();
```

Final code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script>
function change() {
    document.getElementById("two").focus();
}
</script>
</head>



<body>
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="name" onchange="change()" /> 

    <input type="text" name="one" id="one" /> 
    <input type="text" name="two" id="two" /> 
</body>
</html>
```